# input type not working in IE 7 & 8 with anchor <a> & <span> tags

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Following is my code:

```
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" id="quotenow" class=""> <span class="blue_btn"><input type="submit" value="Quote Now" class=""></span> </a>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7hDED/2/ works fine for me, check your <?php echo url part

Comment: When use submit,it means submiting a form.If you don't have to submit a form,why not change it to button?

Comment: Why would you need to put a submit button in an anchor anyway? Perhaps you are confusing what these elements are for.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is wrong, you don't need anchor tags around an input element. It should look something like:

```
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" id="quotenow" class=""><span class="blue_btn">My Anchor</span></a>
```

Or, if you wanted an onclick event on the button then you can do:

```
<!-- this uses javascript to get the result. 
     Typically button and input elements are 
     processed by a form which you'll see in the demo -->
<button onclick="window.open('<?php echo $url; ?>', '_self'); return false;"><span class="blue_btn">My Button</span></button>
```

Here are the rules with that **The element input must not appear as a descendant of the a element.** Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rqrS4/).

Comment: The difference is that a link doesn't depend on javascript, a button does.

Comment: @RobG The button element doesn't have to depend on javascript. It has to be processed by a form element. This just outlines two different ways to get the same thing.

Comment: —a button only "works" without javascript when acting as a submit button a form, a submit button (and other user actions) can do that. I suppose the OP could replace the link with a form and action attribute: `<form action="<?php echo $url; ?>"><button>Quote Now</button>`.